# Using printf and incrementally increasing a string variable?

Tags: awk

I am trying to output a string but I need a number in front of the string to increase incrementally until it ends. I am pulling the data from a txt file.

```
/Circle/{n=split($2,array,",")
if (index(array[2],"x")){x=array[3]}
else if (index(array[2],"y")){y=array[3]}
else if (index(array[2],"z")){z=array[3]}
else if (index(array[2],"r")){z=array[3]}
else { printf("CIRCLE/%.4f,%.4f,%.4f,%.4f\n", x, y, r, z) }}
```

This is what I have currently and it's output is like this

CIRCLE/0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.0068

CIRCLE/10.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.9068

CIRCLE/5.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.8068

and I need it to look like this

CR1=CIRCLE/0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.0068

CR2=CIRCLE/10.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.9068

CR3=CIRCLE/5.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.8068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your printf to:

```
printf("%sCIRCLE/%.4f,%.4f,%.4f,%.4f\n", "CR" ++i "=", x, y, r, z)
```

(Also, it's slightly more idiomatic to not use parentheses with print statements):

```
printf "%sCIRCLE/%.4f,%.4f,%.4f,%.4f\n", "CR" ++i "=", x, y, r, z
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.

Comment: `printf "CR%d=CIRCLE/%.4f,%.4f,%.4f,%.4f\n", ++i, x, y, r, z` would IMHO be more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post any sample input so this is obviously untested but your code should probably look like this:

```
/Circle/ {
    split($2,array,/,/)
    if (array[2] ~ /[xyzr]/) {
        v[array[2]] = array[3]
    }
    else {
        printf "CR%d=CIRCLE/%.4f,%.4f,%.4f,%.4f\n", ++cnt, v["x"], v["y"], v["r"], v["z"]
    }
}
```